# Horizontal click and drag scroller for multiple element at the same time

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, addeventlistener, drag

I want to move one of all selected elements and then all those elements also move simultaneously. but when I drag an element, only one element triggers and the others do not. how can I drag one trigger all?

```
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='parent']");
sliders.forEach((slider) => {
  let mouseDown = false;
  let startX, scrollLeft;

  let startDragging = function (e) {
    mouseDown = true;
    startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
  };
  let stopDragging = function (event) {
    mouseDown = false;
  };

  slider.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!mouseDown) {
      return;
    }
    const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    const scroll = x - startX;
    slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
  });

  slider.addEventListener("mousedown", startDragging, false);
  slider.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDragging, false);
  slider.addEventListener("mouseleave", stopDragging, false);
});
```

```
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.child {
  width: 1000px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
<div>
      <div class="parent" id="parent1">
        <div class="child">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="parent" id="parent2">
        <div class="child">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
          the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If I drag top or bottom element, the others elements should move too at the same time.